# How to pass users' data from nodeJS to reactJS using Express/Mysql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, axios

I need to pass author's email in my posts. I though I can do it by joining tables in my posts route, but it doesn't really work.

Here is my route :

```
router.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.session.user;
  //const usersPosts = await user.$relatedQuery("posts");
  try {
    const user = await User.query().findById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send("User was not found");
    }
    const posts = await Post.query()
      .select([
        "users.email",
        "images.name",
        "posts.category",
        "posts.title",
        "posts.description",
        "posts.created_at"
      ])
      .join("images", { "posts.image_id": "images.id" });
      .join("users", { "posts.user_email": "users.email" });

    console.log("it worked");
    return res.status(200).send({ posts: posts });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(404).send({ response: "No posts found" });
  }
});
```

Here is code with my axios fetching the route :

```
function Home(props) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:9090/posts", {
        withCredentials: true
      });

      console.log(response.data.posts);
      setPosts(response.data.posts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.data);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);
```

And this is how I tried to return it:

```
{posts.map((post, index) => {
          return (
            <>

                      Author:<br></br>
                      <small>{post.user_email}</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      Category:<br></br>
                      <small>{post.category}</small>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                      Description:<br></br>
                      <small>{post.description}</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      Created: <br></br>
                      <small>{post.created_at}</small>
```

Everything works except the fetching Author.

Answer (score 0):

a typo its `user_email` not `users_email` 
your sending email in the value assingned to user_email and in front end using users_email

Comment: I changed it and tried again - nothing happened. Still not getting the author's data.

Comment: have you consoled `posts ` check whether it's having  user_email or not

Comment: restart the node server once

Comment: I cant see now the posts at all, getting 404 error of the whole posts route

Comment: 404 then the issue must be with the api check the backend code or update the code